# Cannot retrieve a particular column

Tags: sql

Consider the table below:

| id | recordDate | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/11 | 10 |
| 2 | 25/11 | 20 |

I am trying to find out `id` with higher temperature compared to its previous dates (yesterday).

Base query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Weather w1
JOIN Weather w2
ON w1.recordDate < w2.recordDate
```

However, when I put this base query into a CTE and use it to filter out the final result on the condition, I get an error.

Final Code:

```
WITH tempComparisons as (
    SELECT *
    FROM Weather w1
    JOIN Weather w2
    ON w1.recordDate < w2.recordDate)
SELECT w2.id
FROM tempComparisons 
WHERE w2.Temperature > w1.Temperature
```

I receive this error:

`Duplicate column name 'Id'`

Why I am facing this issue? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Also please add sample data, including more than 2 records for starting data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*,
             lag(temperature) over (order by recorddate) as prev_temperature
      from weather w
     ) w
where temperature > prev_temperature;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the solution. I am aware of windows and used windows to solve this problem, when trying to use join I am facing this challenge, any suggestions?